# upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04

how can I upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 ?

using the update manager the suggestion is to upgrade to 12.10 but this does not work (fetching the upgrade failed).

Has someone an idea?

BR
Andy

Comment: try `update-manager -d`

Comment: I would do fresh install. More work up front, but seems to make things more stable.